# How to choose source IP from multiple virtual IP's based on specific destination

Tags: linux-networking, iproute2

I am having two private IP attached to an interface.

```
inet 10.255.0.127/24 brd 10.255.0.255 scope global eth1
inet 10.255.0.153/24 brd 10.255.0.255 scope global secondary eth1
```

When traffic leaves the eth1 interface it uses 10.255.0.127 (primary) as the src IP.

How can I change the src IP to use 10.255.0.153 (secondary) based on specific destination.
For example if destination is 10.11.0.0/24 it should use 10.255.0.153 and for everything
else 10.255.0.127 for the same interface eth1.

Comment: you could add static route. 10.11.0.0/24 via 10.255.0.153 dev eth1 and then for the rest: default via 10.255.0.127 dev eth1

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a static route, you can use iptables to achieve the desired source address:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -d 10.11.0.0/24 -s 10.255.0.127 -j SNAT --to-source 10.255.0.153
```